# Can you force a two-typed generic to ensure those types are not identical?

Tags: swift, generics, where-clause, swift5

Is it possible to restrict the below generic to ensure T1 and T2 are not the same type?

Here's what I'm trying to do (but it won't compile)...

```
class Foo<T1, T2> where T1 != T2 {
}
```

Given these types...

```
class A{}
class B{}
class SubA : A{}
```

These should be valid...

```
let w = Foo<A, B>()
let x = Foo<B, A>()
```

Since Swift's generics don't perform type erasure, I believe this should also be allowed (but it's ok if it isn't. This is just for 'completeness' in the discussion)...

```
let y = Foo<A, SubA>
```

This however should not be allowed...

```
let y = Foo<A, A>
```

Now I can put a check in the constructor to ensure that's the case, but I'm wondering if I can do this at compile-time with the 'where' clause, but I haven't been successful.

Using Swift 5 if it matters.

Comment: I don't know what the correct math lingo to describe this is, but all of the typing in Swift, as far as I can tell, is "additive". You can make do an "and" of types (`T1 & T2`), you can require exact types (`T1 == T2`), add subtype relationships (`T1: T2`), but you can't do anything "negative". You can't say `T1 != Int`, `T1 not subclass of T2`, etc. ...

Comment: ... Fundamentally, types are just labels on sets of supported operations. Adding constraints to a type variable decreases the number of possibly-applicable types, but increases the utility of the type var (by guaranteeing that more operations are available). There's something to be gained by saying `T: CustomStringConvertible`, you know that you can call its `var description: String`. On the flip side, there's nothing to be gained from saying `T not subtype of CustomStringConvertible`. Which begs the question: what're you trying to express with such a feature, if it were to exist?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica "Fundamentally, types are just labels on sets of supported operations." This isn't true in Swift. `struct X{}` and `struct Y{}` are different types, even though they're identical. And `protocol P {}` and `protocol Q{}` are also different protocols, and a given type can be conformed to P but not to Q.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the answer to the question is no, but what would you do with it if you had it?

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, I simplified. I believe the correct terminology is that that Swift types are "nominal" (identity based on their name), not structual (identity is based on their structure). But as far as end-users of Swift (developers) are concerned, the importance of types (in a "what can it do for me?" sense) is their ability to guarantee the support for certain operations.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That's often not true. For example, phantom types permit using types with identical structure for the purpose of distinguishing other types. SwiftUI does this surprisingly often (PreferenceKey in particular). I assume you've read it, but for anyone following along here, the best discussion of this is "Protocols are more than Bags of Syntax" https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/

Comment: @RobNapier yep I've run into that article before, interestingly because I was reaching for a "a default constructive protocol"  too, for initializing empty collections in an extension on collection, IIRC. Expressing [`concepts`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_(generic_programming)) isn't the only purpose of Swift's protocols, but it is *one* of them. Expressing that a type conforms to a concept adds value (it supports those features, so you can use them). Expressing that a type doesn't conform to a  concept doesn't add value (you know a certain operation isn't available so what?)...

Comment: @RobNapier I suppose that it's possible that a `T1 != T2` form could make use of the type's "container for semantics" role (as opposed to its "concept role") to add some kind of value, but I really can't think of any examples where that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach, with compile-time generated errors for same types and passed for different types.

*Tested with: Xcode 11.2 / Swift 5.1.2*

[image: generics type checking to avoid same types]

```
class A {}
class B {}

class Foo<T1, T2> {
    private init() {}
}

extension Foo where T1: A, T2: B {
    convenience init(_ a: T1, _ b: T2) {
        self.init()
    }
}

extension Foo where T1: B, T2: A {
    convenience init(_ b: T1, _ a: T2) {
        self.init()
    }
}
```

and testing...

> ```
> let test1 = Foo(A(), B())
> let test2 = Foo(B(), A())
> let test2 = Foo(A(), A()) // << Error: Ambiguous reference to initializer 'init(_:_:)'
> let test2 = Foo(B(), B()) // << Error: Ambiguous reference to initializer 'init(_:_:)'
> let test3 = Foo<String, String>() // Error: 'Foo<T1, T2>' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
> ```

**Update: for Rob Napier comments**

[image]

Comment: This feels a bit wrong. In the test1 case, how would you actually pass the parameters? Can you try this, but actually assigning properties?

Comment: Who said that there should be properties? It can be delegating, calculating, factoring, etc... properties are a different question.

Comment: I mean, actually do anything with `a` and `b` in your init. I believe this solution relies on the fact that they're ignored. If they aren't ignored, I'm not certain it still works.

Comment: What if there are no parameters at all?  Think `var foo = Foo<String, String>()`.  That wouldn't give any compile-time issues.  It's ok... I think I just have to use a bailable initializer and go from there.

Comment: To disallow cases like `Foo<String, String>()` it is possible to make default constructor private as `private init() {}`, so those cases generate compiler error as well (*'Foo<T1, T2>' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level*)